# Order of refinement of an open covering of $X$, a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If every finite open covering of a metric space $X$ has a refinement of order $\leqslant n$, is it true that every open covering does too?

We say that a covering has order $n$ if $n$ is the largest natural number $m$ such that there are $m+1$ members of the  covering which have a non-empty intersection.

And what about $X$ separable?

Until now, this is what I got:

Hypothesis: every finite open covering of a metric space $X$ has a refinement of order $\leqslant n$

Let $\{A_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in \Lambda}$ be an open covering of $X$ and $\tilde{\Lambda}=\Lambda \setminus \{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_m\}$, for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ fixed. Then, the collection $$A_{\alpha_1}, A_{\alpha_2}, \ldots, A_{\alpha_m}, \bigcup_{\alpha \in \tilde{\Lambda} } A_{\alpha}$$is a finite open covering of $X$, consequently there is a refinement $$\tilde{A}_{\alpha_1}, \tilde{A}_{\alpha_2}, \ldots, \tilde{A}_{\alpha_m}, \tilde{A}= \bigcup_{\alpha \in \tilde{\Lambda} } \tilde{A}_{\alpha}$$with order $\leqslant n$.

It would be sufficient that this union was disjoint, but I can't demand it.

It seens easier when $X$ is separable, since every covering has a countable subcovering (and every subcovering is a refinement), but I couldn't finish either, even in this case.

Comment: You could use that every cover has a locally finite refinement first, maybe (i.e. metric spaces are paracompact).

Comment: According to the Encyclopedia of General Topology (f-3, dimension theory), for normal spaces we have that the property for finite covers is equivalent to the one for locally finite ones, and then they remark that thus for paracompact spaces we can replace finite covers by any open cover. They provide no proofs.

Comment: Theorem 7.2.4. in Engelking's general topology (the Dowker theorem) shows the fact that for normal spaces we can go from locally finite to finite covers. And then as said, you are done, using paracompactness.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I think it'll work out!